# Seg Fault after Double Pointer only on Linux OS

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc, segmentation-fault

I am writing code for an assignment and came across an error that I don't understand.  I get a segmentation fault when declaring

```
maxWinnerTreeNode** node = new maxWinnerTreeNode*;
maxWinnerTreeNode *current;
for(int i = 1; i <= numNodes; i++){
    current = new maxWinnerTreeNode();
    node[i] = current;
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is declare an array of treeNode pointers to initialize a full and complete binary tree where I create the tree from the bottom up.  I write and test this code on Windows OS and then submit it to the instructor who tests it on a Linux OS.  The above double pointer declaration doesn't give me any issue on Windows.  As soon as I compile on Linux it throws a seg fault.  I debugged on the Linux server and found I have to declare it as

```
maxWinnerTreeNode** node = new maxWinnerTreeNode*[numNodes];
maxWinnerTreeNode *current;
for(int i = 1; i <= numNodes; i++){
    current = new maxWinnerTreeNode();
    node[i] = current;
}
```

where numNodes is the amount of nodes I need to initialize this complete and full binary tree (some power of 2).  So my question is why does the Linux machine gripe about not initially  knowing the size for the first pointer.  I was under the impression the pointer declaration is a way to dynamically create an array.

I'm running gcc version 4.8.1 on Windows.  The Linux server the code gets graded on runs gcc 4.6.4.  The only obvious answer is the difference in versions.  Just wondering if anyone else has any other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
maxWinnerTreeNode** node = new maxWinnerTreeNode*;
```

allocates memory for exactly one element, so yes, you need to provide the array size here.  If someone told you this is a way to allocate memory dynamically he meant that you can determine the array size at runtime, in constrast to static arrays where you have to provide the array size at compile time.  But operator new always needs to know the exact array size.  This works on Windows just by luck, it's specified as *undefined behavior*, so on the next Windows machine it might crash as well.
If you want truly dynamic arrays you better go with vector from the standard library.